# Proving $\Gamma(x)$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence, gamma-function

My professor defined Gamma function in the following way:$$\Gamma(z)= \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!n^z}{z(z+1)....(z+n)}$$
Now we first observe that $f_n(z)= \frac{n!n^z}{z(z+1)....(z+n)}$ is holomorphic in ${\operatorname{Re} z>0}$. Then we have to show that the limit exists and also that $f_n$ converge uniformly. But I am unable to show that limit exists also I cannot prove that $f_n$ converge uniformly. If anyone can give a hint, it would be really great. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing the limit for $\Gamma(z+1)$ (which is a tad easier) we get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({n\over n+1}\right)^z\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+{z\over j}\right)^{-1}\left(1+{1\over j}\right)^z\qquad (*)$$

we see that

$$\left(1+{z\over j}\right)^{-1}\left(1+{1\over j}\right)^z=1+{z(z-1)\over 2j^2}+O\left(j^{-3}\right)$$

implies convergence of the product and existence of the limit. (I assume you're familiar with infinite products, if not please say so and I'll edit). You can see uniform convergence in the desired region easily from this estimate as well.

---

In case you cannot see it, here is a proof of $(*)$:

Note that

$$\left(1+{z\over j}\right)^{-1}=\left({j\over z+j}\right)$$

so that

$$\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+{z\over j}\right)^{-1}={n!\over (z+1)(z+2)\ldots (z+n)}$$

and

$$\left(1+{1\over j}\right)^z=\left({j+1\over j}\right)^z$$

so that

$$\prod_{j=1}^n \left(1+{1\over j}\right)^z$$

is a telescoping product with value $(n+1)^z$.

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it but I think you missed out a $z$ in the denominator

Comment: @happymath actually, I forgot that this is done for $\Gamma(z+1)$ first, which is a little easier, since you avoid index issues in the product, but it amounts to the same thing, yes. (I also edited the answer to reflect this).

Comment: I am having trouble proving the estimate especially for $(1+\frac{1}{j})^z$ can you please give a hint

Comment: @happymath use a partial geometric series for $\left(1+{z\over j}\right)^{-1}$ and a partial binomial series for $\left(1+{1\over j}\right)^z$

Comment: how can i justify that other terms do not add up too much in the series for $(1+\frac{1}{j})^z$

Comment: because all of the powers of $j$ are to exponents $<-2$. Remember, you have a fixed $z$ with positive real part, so it doesn't affect convergence, it's treated like a constant. What all matters is just the $j$ powers decreasing quickly enough when you add them up.

Comment: I have a doubt please let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20051/discussion-between-happymath-and-adam-hughes).